# Get characters in between last occurrence of a string and another string

Tags: php, string, preg-match, strrchr

I want to get get the text in between the last occurrence of a string and another string

The following does not seem to work:

```
preg_match('/'.preg_quote('{').'(.*?)'.preg_quote($rddaddress).'/is', $apiurlTXinfo, $statTXinfogot);
    preg_match('/' . strrchr($statTXinfogot[1], '"value":"') . '(.*?)","/',$statTXinfogot[1], $TXinfogot);
```

$statTXinfogot returns what it is supposed to but $TXinfogot returns from the start of $statTXinfogot[1] to: "," . I want it to return starting from the last occurrence of : "value":"

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the slow response.
Here is how:
Say we got a string:

```
      $string = "Bubble the octopus in the  noble bubble in an ocean.";

          echo substr($string, strrpos($string, 'bubble') + strlen('bubble'), 
           (strrpos($string, '.') - strrpos($string, 'bubble') -strlen('bubble'));
```

Output: in an ocean

Comment: How can I use this to get the last occurrence of a string?